# MySQL installed with Brew is refusing to start

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I've installed mysql using brew:

```
MacBook-Air-Pavel:mysql paus$ sudo brew install mysql
==> Installing mysql
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-5.6.24.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Pouring mysql-5.6.24.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24: 9719 files, 338M
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to staet mysql.server, it crashes with this message:

```
MacBook-Air-Pavel:webogram paus$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Air-Pavel.local.pid).

MacBook-Air-Pavel:webogram paus$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've no idea why it happens. Could you help me to avoid this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/

Comment: DO NOT use brew with sudo. uninstall it and reinstall without sudo. that may well be your problem

Comment: @blairmeister I tried to reinstall without sudo as you said and got this: http://paste.org.ru/?6c349o

Comment: brew uninstall mysql  then go to where brew installed mysql and delete anything thats left over if anything. then do the install again. the log looks like you didn't uninstall

Comment: @blairmeister How to find where mysql was installed by brew? using find / | grep mysql?

Comment: the default location is /usr/local/Cellar

Comment: @blairmeister it was uninstalled correctly: http://paste.org.ru/?8ojolp

Comment: it looks like you have tried to install mysql with another method, and now trying to use homebrew, yes?

Comment: Yes, I have the mysql 5.6.24 version previously installed from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql.

Comment: @blairmeister but unfortunately, I have no idea how to remove it or call mysql -u from that insatallation.

Comment: where did you install that mysql installation?

Comment: try deleting /etc/my.cnf as well and try again

Comment: I uninstalled everything according this description for "pkg" installation case: http://akrabat.com/uninstalling-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard/ but it didn't help. I don't have /etc/my.cnf in /etc/.

Comment: try sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*

Comment: also have a search with sudo find / -iname "*mysql*"

Comment: @blairmeister here is the list of found "mysql" files: http://paste.org.ru/?e6231e. In particular, brew argued on /usr/local/share/doc/mysql...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79094/discussion-between-blairmeister-and-paus).